# Can a Firestore DocumentReference be passed in an arrayUnion method?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm attempting to add a Firestore Document Reference to an array field in a user document to save the reference as a "favourite". I can read from the array of Document References but cannot use arrayUnion to update the array or arrayRemove to remove an element from the array.

Here is my code to add a reference to the array:

```
await userDocument.reference.updateData({'favourites':FieldValue.arrayUnion([documentReference])});
```

And to remove a reference from the array:

```
await userDocument.reference.updateData({"favourites":FieldValue.arrayRemove([documentReference])});
```

The problem lies with an error appearing which is as follows:

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'DocumentReference'
```

From my understanding this means that a DocumentReference cannot be accepted by arrayUnion/arrayRemove methods.

If this is indeed the case, is there a way around this? And why does Firebase allow you to add references in the project console but not through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug within `cloud_firestore: 0.13.0 to 0.13.1+1` as mentioned in my bug report here: [GitHub: DocumentReference doesn't convert to FieldValue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1986).

It can currently be resolved by reverting back to `cloud_firestore: 0.12.11`

Answer (score 1):

You're dereferencing `documentReference`, which isn't possible.

So you'll want to do:

```
FieldValue.arrayUnion(documentReference)
```

Instead of:

```
FieldValue.arrayUnion([documentReference])
```

Comment: I've already tried this but it throws an error: "The argument type 'DocumentReference' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'."